# Coq: How to prove max a b <= a+b?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am unable to prove the simple logic `max a b <= a+b` using coq's tactics. How should I go about solving it? Below is the code that I worked on till now. `s_le_n` is proved but not mentioned here for the sake of simplicity.

```
Theorem s_le_n: forall (a b: nat),  a <= b -> S a <= S b.
Proof. Admitted.

Theorem max_sum: forall (a b: nat), max a b <= a + b.
Proof. 
intros.
induction a.
- simpl. reflexivity.
- rewrite plus_Sn_m. induction b.
  + simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_O. reflexivity.
  + rewrite <- plus_Sn_m. simpl. apply s_le_n. rewrite IHa.
```

Comment: Sorry not terribly familiar with coq-tactic, but if this is a math question in general max(a,b) <= a + b is NOT true. Example a = 10, b = -20.

Comment: @DoesData: here in coq, i am trying to prove for natural numbers which in coq are all values > 0.

Comment: @AntonTrunov: edited the question

Comment: The proof is less than 40 characters using the library, I could post it; however, let me ask you something, how would you prove this lemma using pen and paper?

Comment: @ejgallego if a>b max a b = a, a < a+b; else max a b = b, b < a+b. I am unable to use this logic in coq. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account @re3el comment, we start from their "pen and paper proof":

```
if a>b max a b = a, a < a+b; else max a b = b, b < a+b
```

Let's now translate that into Coq! In fact, the first thing we need to do is case on the decidability of `<`, this is done using the `le_lt_dec a b` lemma. The rest is routine:

```
Require Import Arith.

Theorem max_sum (a b: nat) : max a b <= a + b.
Proof.
case (le_lt_dec a b).
+ now rewrite <- Nat.max_r_iff; intros ->; apply le_plus_r.
+ intros ha; apply Nat.lt_le_incl, Nat.max_l_iff in ha.
  now rewrite ha; apply le_plus_l.
Qed.
```

However, we can improve this proof quite a bit. There are various candidates, a good one using the stdlib is:

```
Theorem max_sum_1 (a b: nat) : max a b <= a + b.
Proof.
now rewrite Nat.max_lub_iff; split; [apply le_plus_l | apply le_plus_r].
Qed.
```

Using my library of choice [math-comp], you can chain the rewrites to get a more compact proof:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Theorem max_sum_2 (a b: nat) : maxn a b <= a + b.
Proof. by rewrite geq_max leq_addl leq_addr. Qed.
```

In fact, on the light of short proof, maybe the original lemma was not even needed in the first place.

edit: @Jason Gross mentions another style of proof a more seasoned used would use:

```
Proof. apply Max.max_case_strong; omega. Qed.
```

However, this proof involves the use of a heavyweight automation tactic, `omega`; I strongly advise all beginners to avoid such tactics for a while, and learn how to do proofs more "manually". In fact, using any of the SMT-enabled tactics, the original goal can be simply solved with a call to a SMT.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is way simpler than what I had gone through to solve it.

Comment: Yup, somehow a lot of Coq teaching is focused on the use of induction; and way less on the use of existing lemmas. In fact, induction is used very rarely  in practice; another weak point I observe is that people have trouble finding the right lemmas for "classical" case analysis. Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't the two `<` in the "pen and paper proof" be `<=`?

Comment: There's also a short proof without ssr: `Require Import Arith. apply Max.max_case_strong; omega`.  It might be nice to mention this in the answer

Comment: Thanks Jason; I tend to prefer not to teach `omega` and other automated tactics to beginners, IMHO it is very important that they learn how to do proofs without automation first.